# Bootstrap button side by side in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem to make the button in table side by side. I have tried `table-responsive` but it didn't work. I really hope that you can help me.
Here is my code. Based on my understanding, `table-responsive` or `table table-bordered table-hover` is from `Bootstrap`. As long I link it in my `index.html`, supposedly it should be fine. 
But now my output is not as I desired. [The button that I have circle should be side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvn6g.png)

P/S: sorry for my english.

```
  <div class=" table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>PPMID</th>
                <th>EPRID</th>
                <th>Release ID</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Release Name</th>
                <th>Application Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="ppmid" type="number" min="1" placeholder="PPMID">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="eprid" type="number" min="1" placeholder="EPRID">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="releaseid" type="text" placeholder="Release ID">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="projectname" type="text" placeholder="Project Name">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="releasename" type="text" placeholder="Release Name">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="applicationname" type="text" placeholder="Application Name">
                </th>
                <th>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>                      
                    </button> 
                </th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredlist |  filter:searchText"><!--false for ascending, true for descnding-->
            <td>{{item.PMID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.EPRID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Releaseid}}</td>
            <td>{{item.projectname}}</td>
            <td>{{item.releasename}}</td>
            <td>{{item.appname}}</td>
            <td>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code. It works just fine. `Button side by side`

Maybe you should try checking if your browser is not in a zoom-in mode or check if the resolution is correct.

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/2jv2etsj/)

**Snippet Example**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class=" table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>PPMID</th>
                <th>EPRID</th>
                <th>Release ID</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Release Name</th>
                <th>Application Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="ppmid" type="number" min="1" placeholder="PPMID">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="eprid" type="number" min="1" placeholder="EPRID">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="releaseid" type="text" placeholder="Release ID">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="projectname" type="text" placeholder="Project Name">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="releasename" type="text" placeholder="Release Name">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" id="applicationname" type="text" placeholder="Application Name">
                </th>
                <th>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>                      
                    </button> 
                </th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredlist |  filter:searchText"><!--false for ascending, true for descnding-->
            <td>{{item.PMID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.EPRID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Releaseid}}</td>
            <td>{{item.projectname}}</td>
            <td>{{item.releasename}}</td>
            <td>{{item.appname}}</td>
            <td>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>
```

Comment: yeah, supposedly my code can work fine because i already link the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> in index. But as shown in your demo in JSFiddle, it's work. I don't  know what to add in the CSS

Answer (score 1):

I think `<td>` do not have enough width for the buttons make them `side-by-side`.

Two solutions:

```
.side-by-side {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; // force buttons not line-break 
}
```

add this CSS for the container `<td>`.
(btw, `flex` is CSS3 property, check browser support [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp))

or give enough fixed width for the `<td>`.